# Starting Windows Service with Domain User Gives: Error 5: Access is Denied

Tags: .net, windows, permissions, windows-services, topshelf

I have a [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) Windows Service that installs and starts just fine when I run it as `local system`.

But when I switch to a domain user (or `network service`), I get the following error:

> Windows could not start the My Cool Custom Service service on Local Computer.
>
> Error 5: Access is denied.

I am left wondering if it is my domain user that I am running the service as that does not have permissions, or if it is me personally that does not have permissions to start a service as a non `Local System` user.

**How can I get this service to start up?**

NOTES:

Things I have tried:

- Granting the domain user full access to the folder that has the binaries.
- Running SubInAcl.exe to grant the domain user permissions to the service.
- Running SubInAcl.exe to grant me permissions to the service.
- Starting the service from a console that has admin permissions:

  - [TopShelf CLI](http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/overview/commandline.html) Command Run: `MyCoolService.exe start`
  - Error: `The service failed to start., System.ServiceProcess.TimeoutException: Time out has expired and the operation has not been completed.`

Comment: You may also need to grant the user the "Log on as a service" right, either via domain group policy (if applicable) or using the Local Security Policy administrative tool.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to try to work around this by running as `Local System` and then impersonating the user I want to make my calls.

Well, turns out that this issue is that my Windows Service starts up a self hosted SignalR service at startup.  That call is what was giving the `Access is Denied` error.

If I let `Local System` start the SignalR service then do the rest of the stuff with my domain user it works fine.

(I will likely post a question on how to grant my user rights to start a SignalR service...)

Comment: Process Monitor (available from the MS web site) might be helpful in tracking down the underlying problem.